# MCSwipeTableViewCell animate cell's alpha and sliding view same time

Tags: ios, uitableview, swipe, alpha

By using `MCSwipeTableViewCell` is there a way to animate cell's alpha while swiping from **1.0** to **0.0** and in the same time the sliding view alpha to be from **0.0** to **1.0**?

I've managed to animate cell's alpha while swiping from 1.0 to 0.0 by using the method `didSwipeWithPercentage`, but the sliding view is also affected:

```
cell.alpha = 1.0 + percentage;
```

Comment: have you tried to dig into MCSwipeTableViewCell.m? It's actually quite easy to understand and well-documented library. Give it a try!

Comment: At the moment that's I'm trying ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'll give you a head start. There's some fine tuning to do.*

First of all, move this property from **MCSwipeTableViewCell.m** to **MCSwipeTableViewCell.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *contentScreenshotView;
```

---

Then in the didSwipeWithPercentage delegate method:

```
// When the user is dragging, this method is called and return the dragged percentage from the border
- (void)swipeTableViewCell:(MCSwipeTableViewCell *)cell didSwipeWithPercentage:(CGFloat)percentage {

    // swiping from right won't cause negative value
    if (percentage < 0) {
        percentage = -percentage;
    } 

    double start = percentage * 3;
    cell.contentScreenshotView.alpha = 1.0 - start;
}
```

---

### The logic:

In order to produce the swiping effect, the library creates a snapshot of the cell and moves it, thus creating the swiping effect. The above code is referencing the snapshot instead of the cell.